# How can I catch components errors on server in angular universal?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, angular-universal, server-side-rendering

This my server code, next fragment render angular `home.comnponent`:

```
app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    res.render(
        `../${CLIENT_DIST_DIR}/index`,
        {
            req: req,
            res: res,
            providers: [
                {
                    provide: REQUEST, useValue: (req)
                },
                {
                    provide: RESPONSE, useValue: (res)
                },
                {
                    provide: "ORIGIN_URL",
                    useValue: (`${http}://${req.headers.host}`)
                }
            ]
        },
        (err, html) => {
            if (err) {
                Log.error("NG render error", err);
                throw err;
            }
            res.send(html);
        }
    );
});
```

This my `home.component` with error:

```
@Component({
    selector: "app-home",
    templateUrl: "./home.component.html"
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private http: TransferHttpService,
                @Inject(AppStorage) private appStorage: Storage) {
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
         let t = null;
         console.log(t["sd"]["sd"]["sd"]);
    }
}
```

In console I get error, it's ok:

> ```
> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'sd' of undefined
>     at HomeComponent.ngOnInit (nodejs\dist\proxy\server.js:1402:58876)
>     at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (nodejs\dist\proxy\server.js:47324:19)
>     at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (nodejs\dist\proxy\server.js:48588:20)
>     at checkAndUpdateNode (nodejs\dist\proxy\server.js:48550:16)
> ```

But with this condition in the callback does not work:

```
.....
(err, html) => {
                if (err) {
                    Log.error("NG render error", err);
                    throw err;
                }
                res.send(html);
            }
.....
```

In here, `err == null`. Why?

I want to log such errors on the server and write them to a file.

How to do it?

Comment: have you checked the terminal where server is running, i think it's printing in terminal.
may be express render engine generating html with error without giving error

Comment: @RaviSevta yes, it work locally. The problem is that the `err` is always `null`. I set view engine like this: `app.set("view engine", "html");
app.set("views", CLIENT_APP_DIR);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why it does not work, but as a workaround you could try implementing a custom error handler, which will catch that kind of error and assign it to a variable provided server side

**angular error handler**

```
import {Optional, Injectable, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class CustomErrorHandlerService extends ErrorHandler{

  constructor( @Optional() @Inject('ERROR_WRAPPER') private errorWrapper: any ) { 

  }

  handleError(error: Error) {

    console.log('Custom Error Handler error: ' + error.toString());
    if(this.errorWrapper)//serverSide
    {
        this.errorWrapper.error = error;
    }
  }

}
```

**app module**

```
  providers: [
  //...
  {
    provide: ErrorHandler, useClass:
    CustomErrorHandlerService
  }]
```

**universal server**

```
app.get("*", (req, res) => {

    let errorWrapper = {
    error: any;
    }

    res.render(
        `../${CLIENT_DIST_DIR}/index`,
        {
            req: req,
            res: res,
            providers: [
                {
                    provide: REQUEST, useValue: (req)
                },
                {
                    provide: RESPONSE, useValue: (res)
                },
                { 
                    provide: ERROR_WRAPPER, useValue: (errorWrapper)
                },
                {
                    provide: "ORIGIN_URL",
                    useValue: (`${http}://${req.headers.host}`)
                }
            ]
        },
        (err, html) => {
            if (err) {
                Log.error("NG render error", err);
                throw err;
            }
            if(errorWrapper.error)
            {
                //handle your error here
            }
            res.send(html);
        }
    );
});
```

If you just want to throw your error as is, you could directly use the `RESPONSE` token and set correct status code and body in the error handler

Comment: Where does `ERROR_WRAPPER` come from?

Comment: You can use the name you want (as long as provider and component use the same), but the best would be to create an injection token

Comment: But when I call `ERROR_WRAPPER` at serve.ts, `ERROR_WRAPPER` expects a import reference

Comment: try using quotes in `server.ts`, such as `provide: 'ERROR_WRAPPER',`

Comment: you dont seem to interact with error wrapper on callback, how does the error get into the callback error object with your custom errorWrapper object? since it is a custom object i dont see where you tell angular to send the error into the res.render callback

Comment: oh and also you are using typescripts "any" inside running code instead of typescript part. you cant define a type with let errorWrapper = {something: any}, and injection tokens with brackets dont seem to work either